# Search for an element in an array column wise and return the indexes of columns that do not contain the element

Tags: python-3.x

I have a 2d array of size 76 by 273.

I want to search all 273 columns for '0' and return the indexes of columns that do not contain '0'. What is the fastest way to do it in python?

Thanks in avance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any faster way then checking all the cells. If your columns are the first index (i.e. this gets you a column: `array[0]`) then you could use `all`, which checks if all values in an iterable are `True`. Because in Python all integers except 0 count as `True` and 0 as `False` when converted to a `boolean`, this works, but it still isn't faster, because it still needs to check every cell.

With `all`:

```
for i in range(len(array)): # or use 273 instead of len(array)
    if not all(array[i]):
        print(i, "contains 0")
```

If your first index is the row:

```
for i in range(273): # or use len(array[0])
    for j in range(len(array)): # or use 76
        if array[j][i] == 0:
            print(i, "contains 0")
```

Note that the second method will be less cached less efficiently, but there isn't really a better way, if your data is structured like this.

If you want to return the columns that contain zero instead of printing them you can store the to a list e.g.:

```
def zero_cols(array):
    output = []
    for i in range(273):
         for j in range(len(array)):
             if array[j][i] == 0:
                 output.append(i)
    return output
```